# Corrupted value in Arduino array

Tags: c++, arrays, arduino

The program's supposed to constantly listen for 433 MHz messages coming from soil moisture sensors in plant pots and decide whether or not to activate a pump based on those readings.
Additionally it's supposed to check wired water sensors while it's listening.

All 433 MHz Received Messages should be stored within the array `sensor_data[i]`.
At startup  the positions `1`to `NUM_Sensors`(in this case 3) is filled with the constant int `NO_DATA` (500).
The Problem is, that for some reason I get corrupted Number in the array number 3:

Serial Print:

```
Wired Flower Pots Checked
All Sensors or Timeout reached
Array_Print: 500
Array_Print: 500
Array_Print: 30001
```

In this case the 30001 appears in the array with no specific reason (I guess).. there's no received message.
Here's the code changed to the minimum so that the error occurs:

```cpp
#include <RCSwitch.h>
RCSwitch mySwitch = RCSwitch();
//Receiver Setup for wireless soil moisture readings
unsigned long last_ground_check = 0;
const int NUM_SENSORS = 3;
const uint32_t SENSOR_TIMEOUT = 30000;
int sensor_data[NUM_SENSORS];
uint32_t last_message_time = 0;
uint32_t elapsed = 0;
float total_value = 0;
float real_value = 0;
int count = 0;
const int NO_DATA = 500;
boolean received = false;
//###################//
void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
    mySwitch.enableReceive(INT1); // Interrupt 2 = Pin 2
    delay(1500);
    Serial.println("<><><><><><><><><><><><>");
    Serial.println("          Start         ");
    Serial.println("<><><><><><><><><><><><>");
    for (int i = 0; i <= NUM_SENSORS; i++) {
        sensor_data[i] = NO_DATA;
    }
} // Setup END
void loop()
{
    if (received == false) {
        if (millis() - last_ground_check > 10000) {
            Serial.println("Checking Wired Flower Pot");
        }
        Serial.println("Wired Flower Pots Checked");
        last_ground_check = millis();
    }
    if (mySwitch.available()) { // Start whenever a 433 MHz Message is received
        received = true;
        double value = mySwitch.getReceivedValue();
        delay(1000);
        int sensor_id = 1;
        int sensor_value = 2;
        if (sensor_value >= 0 && sensor_value <= 100) {
            sensor_data[sensor_id] = sensor_value;
            last_message_time = millis();
            mySwitch.resetAvailable();
        }
    }
    byte sensors_reported = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= NUM_SENSORS; i++) {
        if (NO_DATA != sensor_data[i]) {
            sensors_reported += 1; // CODE Gets here because of corrupted Array Value although no message was received
        }
    }
    if (sensors_reported != 0) {
        uint32_t elapsed = millis() - last_message_time;
        if (NUM_SENSORS == sensors_reported || elapsed > SENSOR_TIMEOUT) {
            Serial.println("All Sensors or Timeout reached");

            for (int i = 1; i <= NUM_SENSORS; i++) {
                Serial.print("Array_Print: ");
                Serial.println(sensor_data[i]);
            }
            for (int i = 1; i <= NUM_SENSORS; i++) {
                if (sensor_data[i] < NO_DATA) {
                    count++;
                    total_value += sensor_data[i];
                }
            }

            real_value = total_value / count;
            Serial.print("Soil Moisture: ");
            Serial.println(real_value);
            if (real_value <= 20) {
                //Set Pump ON
            }
            for (int i = 1; i <= NUM_SENSORS; i++) {
                sensor_data[i] = NO_DATA;
            }
            total_value = 0;
            real_value = 0;
            sensors_reported = 0;
            count = 0;
            received = false;
            Serial.println("RESET #### RESET ####");
            delay(5000);
        }
    }
} //LOOP
```

Comment: `sensor_data[NUM_SENSORS]`. So `i <= NUM_SENSORS` in for-loop must be `i < NUM_SENSORS` or else you¡re corrupting memory,

Comment: Yes, your array only has 3 elements, but you treat 4.

Comment: .... thank you very much... stupid mistake..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first allocate an array of size `NUM_SENSORS=3`, and then you continue to use it as if it was of size 4.

Your array has 3 elements `sensor_data[0]`, `[1]` and `[2]`. Your loop condition `i <= NUM_SENSORS` results in accessing `sensor_data[3]` which is just some memory after your last array element. Even if you set `sensor_data[3]` in your setup, if the same memory is referenced by some other variable, the `NO_DATA` will be overwritten.

Index your loops over the data array from `i = 0` to `i < NUM_SENSORS`.